# Internet Explorer 7 overflows containing div

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I'm using [IP Net Renderer](http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/index.php) to view my newly installed [forum](http://www.datesphere.com/forum/) in IE7. If you care to take a look, you can see the forum is overflowing its containing element.

The forum renders correctly in IE8+, FF, Chrome and Safari, but not IE 7. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Add Overflow : hidden :)

Comment: I can't see to reproduce the issue in IE7. Which container are you referring to? I'm not seeing any difference between IE7/IE8 or Chrome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Internet Explorer width issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588894/internet-explorer-width-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.wrapper` class has `width: 85%;` set but no overflow rules. Try adding `overflow: hidden;` to that class.

Also, for good measure, I would suggest you replace the `width: 100%;` declaration in your `.tborder` class with `width: auto;`.

Comment: Hi Phil, I tried both of these things but it didn't work. I actually don't have `width: 85%` set on `.wrapper`. I messed around with declaring it as "auto" but it didn't work. Any other ideas?