# Internet Explorer width issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

*I'm re-posting this question because I only got one response before, and it didn't work. Hopefully someone new will see this and know what to do! *

I'm using [IP Net Renderer](http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/index.php) to view my newly installed forum (http://www.datesphere.com/forum/) in IE7. If you care to take a look, you can see the forum is overflowing its containing element (it's wider than the 960px container I have for my entire site).

I've tried adding `overflow:hidden` to the `.wrapper` class as well as `width:100%` to `.tborder` per advice received on StackOverflow, but it didn't work.

The forum renders correctly in IE8+, FF, Chrome and Safari, but not IE 7. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Can I also suggest that if you're using a Windows box, get Virtual PC and pick up a [virtual hard drive from microsoft with ie7 or 8 installed](https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en).

Comment: IE8 and IE9(probably IE7 also has it don't remember) has developers toolbar where you can change rendering setting to render as IE7 or IE8 or IE9 w/e you want.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Internet Explorer 7 overflows containing div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560873/internet-explorer-7-overflows-containing-div)

Comment: @Chris: -1 for being an exact duplicate of the question he asked yesterday. I know this is a repost, but that is not how StackOverflow works. You are not suppose to post the exact same question, especially since you only asked the first one yesterday.

Comment: @Alastair - what's the protocol for when your question is no longer getting views or responses and hasn't been answered yet? Is there a way to bump it to get visibility?

Comment: @Chris: The first step is to wait more than 1 day. Having only 1 answer in 1 day is not uncommon. Bumping is discouraged and there are measures in place to moderate this. If you are desperate for an answer (in terms of time), then you need to edit the original question to provide more detail, pictures, comparisons, anything to facilitate people answering your question. To that end, I'm having a look, and have some questions, but will ask them on the original question.

Comment: @Chris in addition to Alastair's comment you can also edit your question to change it's title, the content, the tags, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use IE9/8 and run the Developer toolbar you will notice that the global.css that is being generated is different for IE7 from IE8. Take a look at what is generating that Style Sheet for you and see if you can modify it to make the MIN-WIDTH:930px; or MIN-WIDTH:100%;

Or a second option add somewhere after the glboal.css style sheet a inline-style or on page css or link another style sheet **.wrapper { MIN-WIDTH:930px !important; }** or **.wrapper { MIN-WIDTH:100% !important; }** so that it overrides whats generated in the global.css file.

IE7:

```
.wrapper {
    MIN-WIDTH: 970px; MARGIN: auto; WIDTH: 85%; MAX-WIDTH: 1500px
}
```

IE8:

```
.wrapper {
    MARGIN: auto
}
```

Comment: ipinfo.info/netrenderer is still showing it as broken (maybe a caching issue), but browsershots.org is showing that IE7 is rendering correctly now. It's weird because I had all those width attributes on `.wrapper` commented out, but I guess IE7 doesn't detect comments. I just removed them and it fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change your min-width value for your wrapper class. You can set an static width or set it to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Remove #wrapper div
And set IE7 specific .tborder {display:inline-table}